# Putting wisepop up on my html page without editing HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, popup

I have 10-20 html pages in my work-space with different names. How I can put a wise pop up to all/specific HTML pages without changing the actual HTML page code. Basically I want to code this advertisement pop-up on any other file and wanted to publish on all html page.

I want to put this type of add not on main HTML page but at some other place and publish on all pages. Any answer?

Comment: I think you need more than just plain HTML.

Comment: Any client supported code will work for me.